# Strange recursive macro output

Tags: macros, e-tex, recursion, loops

Strange recursive macro output

The code that follows describes a macro that can iterate recursively (i.e, a forloop) and uses e-TeX `numexpr`. It is based on an example found in the [e-TeX manual](http://www.let.rug.nl/alfa/tex/tetex30/etex/base/etex-man.pdf)  (page 9)

The first part of the code is pretty straight forward. In the second definition of `foo`, it appears that the macro loops twice!

```
0,1,2,3,4,5
TeX
TeX
TeX
TeX
TeX
```

Something does not look correct here! It reminds me of closures in JavaScript. Can you explain this behaviour?

There is also a second part to the question. The e-TeX manual defines a similar function as:

```
\def\foo#1#2{\noindent\number#1
\ifnum#1<#2,
\expandafter\foo
\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+1\expandafter}%
\expandafter{\number#2\expandafter}%
\fi}
```

What are all these `\expandafters` used for? They seem unecessary. Shouldn't also the comma be after `\number#1` on line one rather than after the `ifnum`?

Here is my code with all three examples:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\def\foo#1#2#3{\noindent\number#1, \TeX\par
\ifnum#1<#2   
  \foo{\number\numexpr#1+\number#3}{\number#2}{\number#3}%
\fi}

\foo{0}{5}{1}
\bigskip


\def\foo#1#2#3{\noindent\number#1, 
\ifnum#1<#2
  \foo{\number\numexpr#1+\number#3}{\number#2}{\number#3}%
   %\else\relax

\noindent\TeX\par
\fi}


\foo{12}{18}{1}


\bigskip
\def\foo#1#2{\number#1, \TeX\par
\ifnum#1<#2
\expandafter\foo
\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+1\expandafter}%
\expandafter{\number#2\expandafter}% 
\fi}



\foo{12}{18}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I remembered stumbling upon a TUGboat article recently, maybe it can be of help: http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb29-2/tb92jackowski.pdf

Comment: may I suggest that you give different names (`\fooa`, `\foob` etc would be okay) to the different version of `\foo`, so that it's easier to refer to them? Including a name for "the second version of `\foo` with `\else\relax` uncommented", please :-) Also, I'm not sure I understand: do you expect the second version of `\foo` to give the same result as the first one?

Comment: @mpg Thanks. I guess is too late to rename them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For now, I'll answer only your second question, about the example from e-TeX. The `\expandafter` are used to force TeX to actually do the computation before calling `\foo` recursively, and to clear the finale `\fi` so that the recursion is terminal. This isn't strictly necessary but is an optimisation. Here is a way to visually check my first assertion:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\def\foo#1#2{\noindent\number#1
  \ifnum#1<#2,
  \expandafter\foo
  \expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+1\expandafter}%
  \expandafter{\number#2\expandafter}%
  \fi}

\def\noexpfoo#1#2{\noindent\number#1
  \ifnum#1<#2,
  \noexpfoo
  {\number\numexpr#1+1}%
  {\number#2}%
  \fi}

\begin{document}

\tracingmacros1
\foo{1}{5}
\noexpfoo{1}{5}
\tracingmacros0

\end{document}
```

After compiling this file, look at the log. You can check that the last call of `\foo` has arguments `5` and `5`, while the last call to `\noexpfoo` has `\number \numexpr \number \numexpr \number \numexpr \number \numexpr 1+1+1+1+1` as its first argument, which is essentially a representation of 5 in base one, as opposed to its base ten representation used in the `\expandafter` case. The size of the first argument grows exponentially in the no-expandafter case. This is very bad and will make TeX crash due to lack of memory, or at least run very slowly, for big loops.

Clearing the final `\fi` serves the same purpose of making the macro more scalable, in a different way. Without the final `\expandafter` in the definition of `\foo`, at the final call, TeX's input stack would look like `\foo{5}{5}\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi`, with all the associated information about with macro call the different `\fi` are coming from. With the final `\expandafter` (indirectly triggered by the first one), the input stack looks like `\foo{5}{5}` without any trailing `\if`.

I'm not including more details about `\expandafter` chaining and the way conditionals expand to keep the answer focused, but feel free to ask if needed.

Also, the comma is after the `\ifnum` test so that you get `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` without a trailing comma-space as in `1, 2, 3, 4, 5,`.

**Complement** about expansion. So, in the definition of `\foo` there are 5 `\expandafter`s and three `\number`s. The first `\expandafter` expands whatever there is after `\foo`, which happens to be the second `\expandafter`, which in turns expands what follows the brace, ie the second `\number` (the first one is earlier in the macro). Now, `\number` tries to read a number expanding everything until it finds something that doesn't belong to a number. Here the right brace will stop that process, but it won't be hit until the third `\expandafter` is expanded, which triggers the fourth `\expandafter`, which in turn triggers the last `\number` which, in the course of processing everything up to the closing brace, triggers the next `\expandafter`, which expands whatever comes after the brace, which is... wait for it... `\fi`.

Now, a common misconception about how TeX handles (expands) conditionals is to forget that the `\fi` is still here. When TeX expands the `\ifnum`, it *doesn't* read everything up to the `\fi`. That's what a macro would do with its arguments: read them entirely. But branches of conditionals *are not* macro arguments. Instead, when expanding `\ifnum` and seeing it is true, TeX just continues reading the rest, making a note to self that the next `\fi` encountered is completely normal and should be silently expanding to nothing. If it encounters a `\else` first, then is will ignore it and everything up to (and including) the closing `\fi`. So, *only* ignored branches are treated as a block.

Comment: Great answer mpg. So essentially the reason for the expandafters is to optimize the code. Would appreciate if you could add a comment or two as to how the expansion work, especially the `\expandafter}\fi}` part

Comment: I added to paragraphs about that. I hope it doesn't bloat the answer too much.

Comment: In the paragraph right after the code listing, do you mean `\noexpfoo` instead of `\foobar`?

Comment: @Willie: right, thanks for spotting that. I edited the answer to fix it.

Answer (score 7):

Now, concerning your first question. There is no double recursion going on. You seem to believe the macros recurse-loops to print `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and the recurse-loops again to print all the `TeX`s. The truth is, there is only one recursion, but the final `TeX` are kept on a pile and poped at the end of the recursion. That is, when the final call to `\foo`is made, TeX's input stream looks like `\foo{arg1]{arg2}{arg3}\noindent\TeX\par\noindent\TeX\par\ETC.`

Here is an example that makes it more visual by changing the output color at each invocation of `\fooX`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\nbcolor[2]{%
  \color{green!\number\numexpr(#2-#1)*100/#2\relax!blue}}

\def\fooa#1#2#3{
  \begingroup \nbcolor{#1}{#2}%
  \noindent\number#1, \TeX\par
\ifnum#1<#2
  \fooa{\number\numexpr#1+\number#3}{\number#2}{\number#3}%
\fi \endgroup}

\def\foob#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup \nbcolor{#1}{#2}%
  \noindent\number#1,
\ifnum#1<#2
  \foob{\number\numexpr#1+\number#3}{\number#2}{\number#3}%

\noindent\TeX\par
\fi \endgroup}

\def\fooc#1#2#3{
  \begingroup \nbcolor{#1}{#2}%
  \noindent\number#1,
\ifnum#1<#2
  \fooc{\number\numexpr#1+\number#3}{\number#2}{\number#3}%
   \else\relax

\noindent\TeX\par
\fi \endgroup}

\begin{document}

\fooa{0}{5}{1} \bigskip
\foob{0}{5}{1} \bigskip
\fooc{0}{5}{1} \bigskip

\end{document}
```

I hope it makes it clearer that `\foob` loops only once. The last `\TeX` remains from the first call to `\foob`, the last-but-one from the second, etc.

By the way, this has nothing to do with TeX, it's a general fact with recursion: you don't get the same result depending on the relative place of the recursive call and the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks. If you remove the empty line at `fooc`, between `\else\relax` and `\noindent\TeX` the output changes. This is  difficult to understand.

Comment: @Yiannis: The empty line gives you the paragraph break, which is the normal TeX behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want to happen but if you change the second example to

```
\def\foo#1#2#3{\noindent\number#1,\TeX\par
\ifnum#1<#2
  \foo{\number\numexpr#1+\number#3}{\number#2}{\number#3}%
\fi}
       
\foo{12}{18}{1}
```

you will get

> 12, TeX
>
> 13, TeX
>
> 14, TeX
>
> 15, TeX
>
> 16, TeX
>
> 17, TeX
>
> 18, TeX

For the last example, you can judge for yourself if the `\expandafter`s are necessary by taking them out and seeing what happens.  Essentially the `\ifnum` will get evaluated not on a number but on `\number\numexpr#1+1`, which it won't know how to resolve.  You get an infinite loop.

Comment: If you uncomment the `\else\relax` on the second example the behaviour goes back to normal. I am trying to understand how the second loop got created. Please check the output to see what happens. None of the two examples I listed used `\expandafter' and I was wondering if it was possible for the e-TeX example to also be written to avoid these. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Oh, I see.  Sorry to answer prematurely.  I'll have to look more carefully at it.

Comment: I disagree about `\ifnum\number\numexpr`: it's perfectly valid and works.

Comment: @mpg: I agree with your disagreement.  I should edit my answer but I might just upvote yours.